# SAS Hotkey permanent binding

Tags: sas

I know F9 opens the definitions windows in SAS Enhanced Editor but the changes made here seem to last only for the current session.

Is there a way to configure SAS so that the hotkeys stay effective for any subsequent sessions ?

Comment: @Close voter, this sort of question is specifically **on topic** on StackOverflow, as it's asking how to use a programming tool (ie, SAS).  SuperUser is for tools commonly used by non-programmers (like Excel, Word, Windows, etc.); while SAS can be used by nonprogrammers, it's generally understood to be a programming environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the 'Save settings on exit' option is selected in 'preferences' (Menu: Tools -> Options -> Preferences).  This option should be on the 'General' tab.  I can't be sure this will do the trick though but I expect so.

Go here to read more about it:- http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/hostwin/63285/HTML/default/viewer.htm#customizing.htm

Comment: That didn't work but I ended up finding a solution, I'll post it as an answer. Thanks

Comment: That should work, if you're set up right; it certainly does for me.  You may have other issues (among other things, are you definitely in a write-access-to-config-files SAS session?).

Comment: Yes, now it works. It didn't work the first time because I had two SAS sessions open *dum,dum,dum*.

Comment: Ctrl+S also works in the function key window for the changes to stay permanent.

Comment: You can also type 'save' into the command box to save them to your profile.

Answer (score 1):

Typing 'keys' in the command box brings up current assignment of all hotkeys in SAS.  You can edit these and save the keys.  As you noted, you can only have one copy of SAS up and running to do this (or you have to do it on the version you opened first that locked the .profile).

You can also map the hotkeys to several commands.
For example, I have F8 mapped to do the following:
    out;clear;log;clear;wpgm;submit;log;top;

That clears current output (if you still use ods listing), clears the current log, submits contents of program editor, and then positions cursor at top of log window for review.

Cheers,
john